# CentOS installed php72 but command line php isn not working

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm reading the following tutorial on installing PHP 7.2 on CentOS 7 https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

It basically says;

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
sudo yum update
sudo yum install php72
```

Then it says to verify the installation using the standard

```
php --version
```

Which returns the following;

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

BUT, if i type the following;

```
php72 --version
```

It works just fine and returns the version.

The problem is that everything relies on the command php and not php72

Any idea on what i should be doing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please read the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

If you need a single version, using remi-php72 repository, and the **php-*** packages, the command will be **php**.

```
# yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
# yum update
# yum install php-cli
# php -v
```

If you need multiples versions, the **php72-php-*** packages are available, and the command is **php72** or

```
# yum install php72-php-cli
# php72 -v
# scl enable php72 bash
# php -v
```

So, according to your question, you have enable the remi-php72 repository, but installed the php72* packages from the remi-safe repository...

Comment: Oh wow, thats a really good link ... I will look into that ... thank you

Comment: You should consider better highlighting the wizard on your website, as it is easy to miss it. Anyway the repo is great, thanks!

Comment: Wow, answered by non other than Remi himself. @CodeCodeCodeCode you should feel privileged :D

Comment: Thank you, just perfect!

Answer (score 22):

I am not sure what is the cause but this is what you can do

```
whereis php72
```

It will give the path. Something like:

php: /usr/bin/php72

Then you can do:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php72 /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 6):

## The steps which worked for me are

> It removes old **php** and installs **php72**

I followed the same article and stuck on the same issue.

`sudo yum -y remove php*`

`sudo yum install epel-release`

`rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm`

`sudo yum install mod_php72w php72w-opcache php72w-pdo php72w-mysql php72w-mbstring`

`sudo scl enable php72 bash`

`sudo yum update`

---

The instructions which worked for me are from the given link.
[PHP 7.2 on CentOS/RHEL 7.4 via Yum](https://webtatic.com/packages/php72/)

Comment: sudo scl enable was what I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to rely on a "standard" solution such as, e.g., the `alternatives` system. To this end, you might do:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/php php /usr/bin/php72 1
```

This will create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` which is wired via the alternatives system to `/usr/bin/php72`. This has the advantage that in case you would install several php versions, the `alternatives` command allows you to switch among them easily...

Comment: Is that similar to doing this update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php72

Comment: @CodeCodeCodeCode that is assuming that you have already some alternatives for php configured, that command selects the version from the "registered" possibilities...

Answer (score 2):

You have to install php72-php. This adds php binary, httpd config and php.ini files

for solve "php -v" you should install php-cli

> yum install php72-php php-cli

Answer (score 1):

yum install php72w-cli , CLI is the command line interface so you need to install it, check for compatible version.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: This was the solution here :-)