# laravel/framework v6.9.0 requires php ^7.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I just finish my laravel project on my local machine, I want to upload to my server to become live api, okay, I searched, youtubed, googled, or etc.. and found some solution for upload, I just upload my whole project, without `vendor`, and `composer.lock`, not set database config yet. after upload, I run:

`composer install`

it give me some error about php version:

> Problem 1
>       - laravel/framework v6.9.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.33) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5.9) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.

But my php version is:

**PHP Version 7.3.13**

How can I fix this?

Comment: From your quote your php version is `7.1.33`

Comment: Note that CLI and Web can use different versions of PHP. Check your configurations for both with `php -i` on the command line and `phpinfo();` in a browser.

Comment: @adam and how to change this?

Comment: @aynber `php -i` return `PHP Version => 7.1.33` but `phpinfo()` return `PHP Version 7.3.13` , so how can I fix this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @aynber centos 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682813/1007220 might help. You'll need to tweak the numbers based on what's on your system

Comment: @aynber okay, I change my php cli version, php -i and php -v return `PHP Version => 7.3.13` but, still same error, any idea?

Comment: If you upgraded PHP, you need to restart the server for changes to take effect.

Comment: @LobsterBaz I used `reboot` but after `reboot` php version restore to old version, and show old version

Comment: Hello @tourtravel look this link : https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214202148-How-do-I-change-the-PHP-version-my-shell-uses-

Comment: @tourtravel Is there a reason you installed two different versions of PHP on your server? Can you remove the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.bash_profile` on `~` root and add this lines:

```
PATH="/usr/local/php73/bin:$PATH" // make sure your path to php73
export PATH
```

then:

`php -v` -> `reboot` -> `php -v`